# how to create the filter in entries before saving to the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How will I do it? I'm new in Django. I've read already a lot but still incomprehensible to me. I'm creating a subjects enrolled model. And I wanted it to be filtered this way:

If student_id exist lookup into the subject and curriculumterm if they existed it will display error message "Already existed" otherwise it will save the entries.

Here's my model.py

```
class SubjectsEnrolled(models.Model):
    student =  models.ForeignKey(Student)
    STATUS = (
        ('1', 'Passed'),
        ('2', 'Failed'),
        ('3', 'No Grade'),
        ('4', 'Incomplete'),
    )
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
    schoolterm = models.ForeignKey(SchoolTerm)
```

And here's my admin.py

```
class SubjectsEnrolledAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('student', 'get_student_lastname', 'get_student_firstname', 'get_student_course', 'subject', 'grade', 'status','schoolterm')

    search_fields = ['student__student_id','student__last_name', 'student__course__course', 'schoolterm__schoolterm']

    def get_student_lastname(self, instance):
        return instance.student.last_name
    get_student_lastname.short_description = 'Last Name'

    def get_student_firstname(self, instance):
        return instance.student.first_name
    get_student_firstname.short_description = 'First Name'

    def get_student_course(self, instance):
        return instance.student.course
    get_student_course.short_description = 'Course'
```

Hope to have an answer on this one... Thanks...

Comment: I guess you want one Student to be enrolled for more than one subject. In that case, why would you not allow the student if it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

For uniqueness use de Model Meta option unique_together. In your model:

```
class SubjectsEnrolled(models.Model):
    student =  models.ForeignKey(Student)
    ...
    schoolterm = models.ForeignKey(SchoolTerm)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("student", "schoolterm"),)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together note: A manyToManyField cannot be included in unique_together!

As alternative to unique_together you can write your own custom form. The advantage is that you can display a custom error message and do multiple non-standard validation even manyToMany.

1) In admin.py create a custom form:

```
class SubjectsEnrolledForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SubjectsEnrolledForm, self).clean()
        student = cleaned_data.get("student")
        schoolterm = cleaned_data.get("schoolterm")
        if student and schoolterm:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            if student in schoolterm.student_set.all():
                raise forms.ValidationError("Student %s in %s term!"%
                                                 (student, schoolterm))

        # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```

2) In Admin.py create your ModelAdmin and specify the form:

```
class SubjectsEnrolledAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SubjectsEnrolledForm
    ...
```

Note: unique_together is on db-level. A undesired entry can't be made. The form is on validation-level. So de db can accept undesired entries. But this form will never submit them. Other forms or logic can though!